# Download zip file on site that requires authentication using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to download a ZIP file using VBScript that requires authentication. If you go to the site you'll notice it pops up an authentication prompt. The problem I have is after this script runs the ZIP file is too small for what it should be and is corrupt so I can't open it.

My thought is the download isn't working.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
strHDLocation = "C:\Test\file1.zip"
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http:downloadsite/report-id=123456", False, "myidhere", "mypwhere"
xmlHttp.Send()


Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

objADOStream.Write xmlHttp.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
Set objFSO = Nothing

objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
```

Comment: Check `xmlHttp.ReadyState = 4` before processing `xmlHttp.ResponseBody`. Also check `xmlHttp.Status` to make sure you get a `200` HTTP Response.

Comment: So should I be loop until it's the value of 4? I thought Send was blocking? I did that and it is 4 after Send() but still the same issue.

Comment: You set it to not be async so should be blocking but things can happen I always find it best to check regardless of whether it's async or not. It's more likely the server is returning a error though which is why I suggested checking `xmlHttp.Status`.

Comment: Added the check but still same result.

Comment: Did you check `xmlHttp.Status = 200`?

Comment: Ah, forgot 1 letter on the pw! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bare minimum when using `IXmlHttpRequest` you should check the `Status` property to make sure that assumptions are not made about what is being returned.

```vb
If xmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
  'Successful Request
Else
  'Something went wrong
End If
```

It's likely the request has failed for one reason or another and the `ResponseBody` contains the failed response not the expected ZIP file.